# Remix.run & .env : what is the proper way to set an API base url depending on where the code is deployed

Tags: api, environment-variables, remix.run

I'm using Remix.run and I like it.
But I'm stuck with this issue :

I have an API and its base URL need to be different depending on where it is deployed (dev, release candidate, production, etc...)

Without Remix.run framework, I would use .env files and npm build scripts in my CD/CI.

Remix.run approach to .env is different, [the doc](https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/guides/envvars#server-environment-variables) it is explaining that multiple .env files are not detected by remix compiler and, instead, the environment detection should be done on the server and if necessary to pass data to the front end, assign the data to the window object (in the `root.tsx` file).

So,
regarding my problem, this is how I set it on the server side :
In order to detect what environment the script was, I did it based on the URL with something that kind of look like that :

```js
const envData = [
  { url: 'https://dev-example.com/', apiBase: 'https://dev-api-example.com/', name: 'developement' },
  { url: 'https://stg-example.com/', apiBase: 'https://stg-api-example.com/', name: 'staging' },
  { url: 'https://rc-example.com/', apiBase: 'https://rc-api-example.com/', name: 'release-candidate' },
  { url: 'https://example.com/', apiBase: 'https://api-example.com/', name: 'production' },
];

export const getBaseApi = (domain) => {
  ...
  return envData.find((item) => item.url === domain)
}
```

Then, I will trigger this function in **each page** `loader` function and pass the result to all the functions responsible for calling the API.
With something like this :

```js
export const loader: LoaderFunction = async ({ request }) => {
  const apiBase = getBaseApi(new URL(request.url).hostname);
  const userSession = await getUserSession(apiBase);
  const myData = await myApiCall(somedata, userSession, apiBase);
  ...
```

and in the front, I will also have to pass this base URL to each API function :

```js
export default function Favorite() {
  const { userSession, favList } = useLoaderData();

  return (
    <section>
      <div className="px-4">
        <FavList
          list={favList}
          isLogin={userSession.login}
          getList={() => getFavorites(userSession.token, window.API_BASE_URL)}
          toogleFav={(id) =>
            setFavorite(id, userSession.token, window.API_BASE_URL)
          }
        />
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}
```

it works but I am not happy with it TBH.
Do I understand this correctly ?
Is there someone out there that have a more simple and easy to maintain solution ?

Comment: If deploying to Node, you should just read your env from `process.env.*` which should be configured as part of your CI. That way you can read the env vars anywhere (you don't need access to request.url). I usually have an env.ts which validates the variables + conditionally reads from process.env vs window.ENV.

Comment: Also, unless all your secrets are public, you don't want to check them into your repo.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't define your env config in your code as, given it will most likely contain sensitive information, you don't want just anybody who has access to your repo to be able to read it across all environments.

Additionally, you shouldn't rely on `url.hostname` as it can be spoofed.

Instead, assuming you're deploying to Node, you should [read env vars from `process.env.*`](https://nodejs.dev/en/learn/how-to-read-environment-variables-from-nodejs/) which can be [configured as part of your deployment process](https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/guides/envvars#production) (or locally you can [define an .env file](https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/guides/envvars#local-development)).

In Remix, I like to define a `config.ts` file which validates and exports `PRIVATE_CONFIG` & `PUBLIC_CONFIG` objects, allowing you to read them from anywhere in your application, on the server and client as appropriate.

```js
// ~/config.server.ts - Reads & validates env vars from `process.env.*` on the *server* only.
import { z } from "zod";

const privateConfigSchema = z.object({
  DATABASE_URL: z.string().min(1).trim(),
  SESSION_SECRET: z.string().min(1).trim(),
});

// WARNING: These vars will be exposed in the browser.
const publicConfigSchema = z.object({
  API_HOST: z.string().min(1).trim(),
  APPLE_PAY_ENABLED: z.coerce.boolean().default(false),
});

export type PrivateConfig = z.infer<typeof privateConfigSchema>;

export type PublicConfig = z.infer<typeof publicConfigSchema>;

const getSchemaProcessEnv = (schema: z.ZodObject<any>) => {
  return Object.keys(schema.shape).reduce<Record<string, any>>((acc, curr) => {
    acc[curr] = process.env[curr];
    return acc;
  }, {});
};

export const _PRIVATE_CONFIG: PrivateConfig = privateConfigSchema.parse(
  getSchemaProcessEnv(privateConfigSchema) as any
);

export const _PUBLIC_CONFIG: PublicConfig = publicConfigSchema.parse(
  getSchemaProcessEnv(publicConfigSchema) as any
);
```

```js
// ~/config.ts - Conditionally reads env var from `window.*` or `process.env.*` depending whether on client or server.
import type { PrivateConfig, PublicConfig } from "./config.server";
import { _PRIVATE_CONFIG, _PUBLIC_CONFIG } from "./config.server";

export const PUBLIC_CONFIG: PublicConfig =
  typeof document === "undefined"
    ? _PUBLIC_CONFIG
    : (window as any)._PUBLIC_CONFIG;

export const PRIVATE_CONFIG: PrivateConfig =
  typeof document === "undefined"
    ? _PRIVATE_CONFIG
    : new Proxy({} as PrivateConfig, {
        get: (target, property) => {
          throw new Error(
            `PRIVATE_CONFIG.${String(
              property
            )} cannot be accessed client side, try PUBLIC_CONFIG.${String(
              property
            )}`
          );
        },
      });
```

```js
// ~/root.tsx - Safely adds PUBLIC_CONFIG to `window` & demonstrates reading PUBLIC_CONFIG & PRIVATE_CONFIG on client & server.
import { json } from "@remix-run/node";
import {
  Links,
  LiveReload,
  Meta,
  Outlet,
  Scripts,
  ScrollRestoration,
  useLoaderData,
} from "@remix-run/react";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import serialize from "~/utils/serialize-javascript.server";
import { PUBLIC_CONFIG, PRIVATE_CONFIG } from "~/config";

console.log("PRIVATE (shared)", PRIVATE_CONFIG);
console.log("PUBLIC (shared)", PUBLIC_CONFIG);

export const loader = () => {
  console.log("PRIVATE (server)", PRIVATE_CONFIG);
  console.log("PUBLIC (server)", PUBLIC_CONFIG);
  return json({ PUBLIC_CONFIG_STR: serialize(PUBLIC_CONFIG) });
};

export default function App() {
  const { PUBLIC_CONFIG_STR } = useLoaderData<typeof loader>();
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("PRIVATE (client)", PRIVATE_CONFIG);
    console.log("PUBLIC (client)", PUBLIC_CONFIG);
  }, []);
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <Meta />
        <Links />
      </head>
      <body>
        <Outlet />
        <ScrollRestoration />
        <script
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
            __html: `window._PUBLIC_CONFIG = ${PUBLIC_CONFIG_STR}`,
          }}
        />
        <Scripts />
        <LiveReload />
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

```js
// ~/utils/serialize-javascript.server.ts
export { default } from "serialize-javascript";
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think you are missing my point.
[Remix only allow 3 build environments](https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/guides/envvars#server-environment-variables) : "production", "development" or "test". But I need to have more than that, as I showed in my example. 
I'm used to having [multiple .env file](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/development-environment/environment-variables/using-multiple-env-files) in the repo (the repo is private in my company server), allowing only the correct API url to be ship in each environment.

Comment: Don't pivot on NODE_ENV. Just set API_BASE as an environment variable and read it. Or if you really feel the need to check-in your config just come up with a new env var which remix doesn't care about, e.g. APP_ENV and pivot on that.

Comment: If your deployment needs the env vars to originate in a file, then you can do that before you run `remix-serve build` using some other lib, maybe using https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

Comment: really sorry for the late answer, I had to switch project last week. Thank you for the advice, it does not have to be on an external file, but it needs to be different depending on the build. I could not finish my test with dotenv and in the end we went with another solution: injecting the value in the Docker settings.  If there is any news regarding this issue I'll update my post